# django raised 'function' object is not subscriptable but local python doesn't

Tags: python, django

I got a strange thing I can't handle and understand. I'm really intrigue

Let me explain,
I coded some stuff locally on my computer with python3 (which run like a charm !! ), I used to transfer this script to my django . And magic happen it's raised an error , I don't have when I run locally ...

here is the script part which seems to create the error :

```
from c***.utils import calculate_distance
from operator import itemgetter
import geopy

solution = []

def is_in_radius(elem1, elem2):
    dict_coord = {
        'pa' : (elem1[3][0],elem1[3][1]),
        'pb' : (elem2[3][0],elem2[3][1]),
    }

    distance = calculate_distance(dict_coord.get('pa'), dict_coord.get('pb'))
    # print("distance : " + str(distance) + " m - entre :  "+ str(elem1[0]) + " et " + str(elem2[0]))
    if (distance <= 1200):
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False)

def last_rad(data_info, elem1, am_act):
    global solution
    if(len(solution) + 1 == am_act):
        if(is_in_radius(elem1, data_info[1]) == True):
            return(True)
        else:
            return(False)
    else:
        return(True)

def first_rad(data_info, elem1):
    global solution
    if(len(solution) == 0):
        if(is_in_radius(data_info[0], elem1) == True):
            return(True)
        else:
            return(False)
    else:
        return(True)
```

Error raised is :

```
'function' object is not subscriptable
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://****.io/new_search
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'function' object is not subscriptable
Exception Location: /home/debian/***/mysite/**/backtrack.py, line 33, in first_rad
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.3
```

line 33 is linked to

```
        if(is_in_radius(data_info[0], elem1) == True):
```

Does someone have an idea on how to manage the error and when it could coming from ?

Thank's a lot !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error when you try to access an attribute from a function similar to a dict.

For example, for the builtin function `max` :

```
>>> max[4]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

Based on that I would suggest that `data_info[0]` is the problem, and `data_info` might not be a list like you expect, but a function.

So the function definition is ok, but it's invoked with wrong parameters I would say. Look where you're invoking it and how you're passing the parameters.

Comment: Thank's david , it was this . You open my eyes to see somewhere else it was the parameters.  Have a nice day !